# Подскажите как правильно вытащить нужные данные из json строки в c#

Tags: c#, json

Нужно вытащить с конкретного API https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=%D0%98%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA&format=json&polygon_geojson=1

Конкретно нужно только данные по тегу coordinates, но для начала решил попробовать хоть строку вытащить.
Пробовал так:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
namespace StackOverFlowQuestion1
{
    class Program
    {
        class OSMData
        {
            int place_id { get; set; }
            string licence { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connection = $"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Ижевск&format=json&polygon_geojson=1";
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
            webClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0";
            string Json = webClient.DownloadString(connection);
            //Json = Json.Remove(Json.Length - 1).Remove(0, 1);
            var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OSMData>(Json); 
        }
    }
}
```

выдаёт ошибку

> " The JSON value could not be converted to
> StackOverFlowQuestion1.Program+OSMData. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 1."

Обратил внимание на нестандартные на мой не очень понимающий взгляд "[]" на концах файла, так что  Если расскоментить закоменченную в программе строчку, то для некоторых случаев проходит, но не записывает ничего в экземпляр класса. В общем что посоветуете сделать? Полностью описывать всё, если так, то подскажите как правильно, парочку полей хотя-бы опишите для аналогии

Comment: Посоветую начать с изучения формата [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Я искренне не понимаю, почему люди, которым надо распарсить json/xml/yaml/csv не читают про устройство этих форматов. Сотни вопросов на ru.so и тысячи на en.so... PS: квадратные скобки - массив (коллекция). Фигурные скобки - объект.

Comment: Там массив, обратите внимание на квадратную скобку в самом начале - `OSMData[] obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OSMData[]>(Json);` или так тоже можно `List<OSMData> obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<OSMData>>(Json);`